# How do I accesses a static variable value for each instance of a class object

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Box {
   public:
      static int objectCount;
      // Constructor definition
      Box(double l = 2.0, double b = 2.0, double h = 2.0) {
         cout <<"Constructor called." << endl;
         length = l;
         breadth = b;
         height = h;
         // Increase every time object is created
         this->objectCount++;
      }

      double Volume() {
         return length * breadth * height;
      }

      static int getID()
      {
          return objectCount;
      }

   private:
      double length;     // Length of a box
      double breadth;    // Breadth of a box
      double height;     // Height of a box
};

// Initialize static member of class Box
int Box::objectCount = 0;

int main(void) {
   Box Box1(3.3, 1.2, 1.5);    // Declare box1
   Box Box2(8.5, 6.0, 2.0);    // Declare box2

   // Print total number of objects.
   cout << "Total objects: " << Box::objectCount << endl;
   cout << "Box1 ID: " << Box1.getID() << endl;
   cout << "Box2 ID: " << Box2.getID() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

How do I access the objectCount of 'Box1' and 'Box2'. 'Box1' is supposed to have an objectCount of 1 while 'Box2' remains 2. e.g

it prints:

> Constructor called.
>   Constructor called.
>   Total objects: 2
>   Box1 ID: 2
>   Box2 ID: 2

instead of:

> Constructor called.
>   Constructor called.
>   Total objects: 2
>   Box1 ID: 1
>   Box2 ID: 2

Comment: You may wish to investigate the difference between a static and an instance variable. Do you get the expected result when you remove the word static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one `objectCount` for the class. That's what a `static` class member is, by definition.

What you need to do is add a non-static member to the class, and initialize it in the constructor.

```
 static int objectCount;
 int my_objectCount;

  // Constructor definition
  Box(double l = 2.0, double b = 2.0, double h = 2.0)
     : my_objectCount(++objectCount)
  {
    // ...
  }
```

Then, `my_objectCount` will be 1 for the first instance of the class, 2 for the second one, and so on.

Comment: " : my_objectCount(++objectCount)"  this initialization in my constructor is giving me error

Comment: What is the error? Did you add the new field as instructed?

Comment: Yes! I add ' : my_objectCount(++objectCount) ' but this gives error

Comment: No, you did not add the new field. Hence the error. Reread the answer please.

Comment: I don't know what he means by this code -> " : my_objectCount(++objectCount) " but it worked when I declare a new variable 'int my_objectCount' private and initialized it in the constructor simply as -> objectCount++;  my_objectCount = objectCount;